# how to resolve imap4 error login failed using oulook?

Tags: python, windows, office365, imaplib

def main():

```
username = os.environ.get("EMAIL_ADDRESS")
password = os.environ.get("EMAIL_PASSWORD")
imap_server = 'outlook.office365.com'

# create an IMAP4 class with SSL
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_server, port=993)
print(imap)
# authenticate
imap.login(username, password)
print(f"Successfully connected to {imap_server} on port 993")
print(f"Logged in as {username}")

# Print IMAP server capabilities
print("IMAP Server Capabilities:")
for capability in imap.capabilities:
    logger.info(f"  {capability}")

# Print selected mailbox information
status, mailbox_info = imap.select('INBOX')
if status == 'OK':
    messages = int(mailbox_info[0])
    print(f"Selected mailbox: INBOX")
    print(f"Number of messages: {messages}")

    # Iterate over the emails
    for _ in range(messages, max(0, messages - 10), -1):  # Process the last 10 emails or fewer
        status, msg_data = imap.fetch(_, "(RFC822)")
        raw_email = msg_data[0][1]
        msg = email.message_from_bytes(raw_email)       
        
else:
    print("Failed to select INBOX")
```

if **name** == "**main**":
main()

here I'm using correct mail and app password and also tried with mail password both are getting same error--- " IMAP4 error: b'LOGIN failed."

how to resolve imap server login issue outlook and this outlook also have MFA.

Comment: For reference, you cannot log into corporate Office365 accounts using a password.  You _must_ use OAuth.  However, I am not sure how you integrate this into php_imap.